# Помощь в составлении сложного SQL запроса

Tags: sql

Как по мимо ``contracts`\`.``skin_win`\`, получить ещё ``contracts`\`.``skins`\` при том что там хранятся `id` в формате `json` пример:

```
{  
  "0": "792",  
  "1": "785",  
  "2": "780",  
  "3": "779",  
  "4": "776",  
  "5": "775",  
  "6": "774",  
  "7": "773"  
}
```

Код для получения `contracts`.`skin_win`
В идеале нужно получить всё одним запросом

```
SELECT 
    `contracts`.`result`, 
    `skins`.`img`, 
    `skins`.`title`, 
    `skins`.`name`,  
    `skins`.`cost`,  
    `skins`.`rarity`  
FROM  
    `contracts`  
    INNER JOIN `inventory` ON `contracts`.`skin_win` = `inventory`.`id` 
    INNER JOIN `skins` ON `inventory`.`item_id` = `skins`.`id`  
WHERE  
    `contracts`.`user_id` = 1  
ORDER BY `contracts`.`id` DESC;
```

В результате мне должно отдать что то по типу
`result`, `skin_win` (если быть точнее его `img`, `title`, `name`, `cost`, `rarity`), `skins` (со skins так же как и skin_win, мне должно вернуть все img, title, name, cost, rarity из `skins`)

таблицу оставил здесь если кто то хочет по тестить: https://dropmefiles.com/i0Om9

P.S. Максимум до чего я смог додуматься, но ошибка:

```
SELECT  
    c.`result`,  
    sw.`img` AS winning_skin_img,  
    sw.`title` AS winning_skin_title,  
    sw.`name` AS winning_skin_name,  
    sw.`cost` AS winning_skin_cost,  
    sw.`rarity` AS winning_skin_rarity, 
    s.`img` AS skin_img, 
    s.`title` AS skin_title, 
    s.`name` AS skin_name, 
    s.`cost` AS skin_cost, 
    s.`rarity` AS skin_rarity 
FROM  
    `contracts` c 
INNER JOIN  
    `inventory` i ON c.`skin_win` = i.`id` 
INNER JOIN  
    `skins` sw ON i.`item_id` = sw.`id` 
CROSS JOIN  
    JSON_TABLE( 
        c.`skins`, 
        '$.*' COLUMNS ( 
            skin_id INT PATH '$' 
        ) 
    ) AS sk 
INNER JOIN  
    `skins` s ON sk.skin_id = s.`id` 
WHERE  
    c.`user_id` = 1 
ORDER BY  
    c.`id` DESC;
```

Comment: [Как задавать хорошие вопросы про SQL?](//ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/169/#1035), пункты 5 и 3. *таблицу оставил здесь если кто то хочет потестить* Лучше всего дополнительно создать fiddle на, например, https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0 и выложить ссылку. А файлообменники - это не наш метод... И да - следует почистить таблицы от ненужных для вопроса полей и оставить в них минимальное, но вменяемое и адекватное количество записей. Поскольку вопрос не о производительности - то из индексов оставить только PK и нужные для FK. *но ошибка* Мы её должны сами придумать?